# How to immediately page-in newly-allocated virtual memory

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management

I allocated some memory in my Linux user-space application.  But, this memory is not yet backed by physical memory.

In an attempt to cause the pages to be mapped, I attempted to read from each page in the region, as shown below.  But it didn't always work for me.

Here is my original code:

```
void Function(void)
{
    char *memory;

    memory = malloc(4096 * 10);
}
```

Allocated like this, the virtual memory is not yet mapped to physical RAM.

So I modified the code thus:

```
void Function(void)
{
    char *memory;
    volatile uint *accessMemory;

    memory = malloc(4096 * 10);
    accessMemory = (volatile uint *)memory;
    for (i = 0; i < 4096 / 10; i++) {
        printf("%X\n", *accessMemory);
        accessMemory = (volatile uint *)((uint)accessMemory + 4096);
    }
}
```

But I still had the same problem.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What actually is the error?

Comment: Sorry this is not a error but i apply security extention in arm processor.     some times i need linux page-table for mapping to my page-table at same physical address. But linux use page-fault mechnisim so didn't mapping physical address to page-table, so i don't read this physical address.         in the linux system, this is not a Bug. but my case this situlation make a bug

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what "Bug" you are talking about, but to be sure that memory is prefaulted and copy-on-write mechanism is avoided (i.e. no page-faults would happen when you try to access memory you allocated), you should use mmap() syscall and pass MAP_POPULATE flag to it.

For example:

```
void *addr;
addr = mmap(NULL, 4096 * 10, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_POPULATE, -1, 0);
```

malloc() uses mmap() internally anyway when large amounts of data are requested (at least 128 kB for glibc, for example - this value is adjustable, though)

See man mmap for details.

Edit: if you want to change the size of your mapping you can use mremap() as an analog of realloc() call. See man mremap.

But you have to be careful with it:

- it is linux-specific,
- it doesn't allow you to prefault additional area,
- it can't guarantee a successful remapping at the same location

So it may not exactly fit your needs. In that case you should consider having several mappings or somehow calculating beforehand how large your mapping should be.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry i learning english.. hehe..  but you catch to my probleam. I will try to your solution.. thanks

Comment: Have a more question.  I want to use realloc how to exchange mmap?

Comment: @user1998727 You may try mremap. I have expanded my answer to give more details about it.

Answer (score 1):

There's an obvious problem with your code, and the cast is a symptom.  You allocate space for 40960 chars, but then attempt to access unsigned 409 unsigned integers each 4096 apart.  Not only that, but you coerce the pointers to uint before performing arithmetic - this may well be a narrowing conversion, and it's definitely unsafe.

You'd be better off declaring your `memory` pointer to be the type as which you intend to use it:

```
    const size_t page_size = 4096; // TODO: get actual value from system
    uint *memory;
    uint *end;
    volatile uint *p;

    memory = malloc(page_size * 10 * sizeof *memory);
    end = memory + page_size * 10;
    for (p = memory;  p < end;  p += 4096/(sizeof *p))
        printf("%X\n", *p);
```

Having said all that, if you wish to work in terms of pages, you may well be better served with `mmap()`; in particular, this option:

> **MAP_POPULATE** (since Linux 2.5.46)
>   Populate (prefault) page tables for a mapping.  For a file mapping, this causes read-ahead on the file.  Later accesses to
>   the mapping will not be blocked by page faults.  MAP_POPULATE is
>   supported for private mappings only since Linux 2.6.23.